# What are the similarities between thermal and kinetic energy

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

I have been curious about thermal and kinetic energy .

Comment: Your question will probably get answers from Google.

Answer (score 1):

IMO "thermal energy" is a nebulous term and should be avoided. Sometimes is is used to mean kinetic energy. Sometimes it is used to mean heat, which it isn't, because heat is energy *transfer* due solely to temperature difference.

On the other hand, the term "kinetic energy" is unambiguous. It is the energy of motion. "Potential energy" is likewise unambiguous. It is the energy of position. All forms of energy can basically be boiled down to kinetic and/or potential energy. The main consideration is whether one is dealing with the macroscopic or microscopic scale, i.e., the motion or relative positions of atoms and molecules, called internal energy, or the motion and position of extended bodies relative to some external frame of reference. For example, the kinetic energy of a thrown baseball relative to the ground.

Hope this helps.